# Is the protocol different for accessing data.dol.gov and api.dol.gov?

Tags: api, labor

Trying to access the DOL API - specifically DOL OSHA Enforcement Data.   Currently using PHP to make the API Call however merely changing the host and URI (from api.dol.gov to data.dol.gov and from /priorDataSet/DataTable to /get/violation/violation for example) does not work...

***Edit***
Don't think the SDK works for data.dol.gov - direct HTTP Requests may work

***UPDATE***
SDK is broken for data.dol.gov. Can be fixed by replacing 'http://quarry.dol.gov' with 'https://data.dol.gov'

Comment: it looks like your update is the solution....correct? if so, feel free to answer your question

Comment: yes, it's correct. They are fixing the PHP SDK soon as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is different, though you can use the same key.  At http://developer.dol.gov/beginners-guide, right above the "Accessing the API" heading, are two tabs.  One is for api.dol.gov, the other is for data.dol.gov.

We'll get the PHP SDK fixed momentarily.